# NSDictionary multiple values with same key?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create an `NSDictionary` that looks like it has duplicate keys, but the values are different.

The reason for this is due tot he web service that I am sending that data it - it accepts a multi-form post message and needs values like this:

```
SomeKey: value1
SomeKey: value2
SomeKey value 3
```

And not like this:

```
SomeKey: value1, value2, value 3...
```

I have the values in an NSArray - however I am not sure how to get them into an NSDictionary that looks like the above - maybe some sort of object?

**Edit**

So, here is how I make a web service request to our main server.

Networking Library: AFNetworking 2.0

From **viewControllerA**

This code runs after a previous web service request has been made:

```
NSDictionary *results = [[BBDataStore sharedDataStore]fetchuserIdResult];
            BBSeller *seller = [[BBSeller alloc]init];

            seller.alias = results[@"userAlias"];
            seller.userId = results[@"userid"];

            [self.sellerListIds addObject:seller.userId];
            [self.sellerListAliases addObject:seller];
```

This splits the data into two arrays:

```
self.sellerListIds
```

Is for the userId which I am really interested in. Its just a `NSString`

```
self.sellerListAliases
```

Is just to display the username on screen to the user - nothing more, really. The web service I need to send this data to, only looks at userIds.

Right - then I call a method

```
[self setupSearchParameters:seller.userId];
```

Which looks like this:

```
    -(void)setupSearchParameters: (NSString *)userId
{

    self.sellerListidString = userId;

    [self.parameters setObject:self.sellerListidString forKey:self.typeOfSellerSearch];
}
```

This allows one userId for the key: `self.typeOfSellerSearch`

Now, when the user presses confirm button to execute the web service search it calls a method in my data start with the self.parameters dictionary and adds other values to an existing dictionary - which include other search keywords.

Finally, it calls the network request method - which looks like this:

```
-(void)fetch:(NSDictionary *)urlParameters
{
    if (!self.webService.isBusy){

        BBWebService *webService = [[BBWebService alloc]initWithURL:self.url RequestType:GET_REQUEST UrlParameters:urlParameters];

        self.webService = webService;
        self.webService.webServiceId = wsID;
        [self.webService setDelegate:self]; 

    }

}
```

That calls this method:

```
    -(instancetype)initWithURL:(NSString *)url RequestType:(NSString *)requestType  UrlParameters:(NSDictionary *)urlParameters
{

    [self getSessionManager];

    if ([requestType isEqualToString:@"GET"]){

        self.isBusy = YES;
        [self.manager GET:url parameters:urlParameters
                  success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){

                      NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;

                      int statusCode = (int)response.statusCode;

                      [self requestDone:responseObject StatusCode:statusCode];

                  }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error){

                      NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;

                      int statusCode = (int)response.statusCode;
                      [self requestFailed:error StatusCode:statusCode];

                  }];
return self;
}
```

From there AFNetworking 2.0 takes care of constructing the parameters into the URL and makes the request. When it comes back successful, I take the data and parse it.

Right now -this works. However, I need it to work with more than one key / value pair.

If I try @Selvin's code the web service doesn't work correctly. I spoke with the Java Develeopers and they say the web service expects this:

Key / value 1 
Key / Value 2
Key / Value 3
.....

it won't work with this:

key / value1, value2, value 3///

Nor does it seem to work with this:

key2 / some random value -> key / value1

As it does't know what key2 is so it ignores it.

Comment: More detail please.  What is the interface to the web service that accepts the dictionary?

Comment: What are you expecting to get when you use `objectForKey:@"SomeKey"`?

Comment: @trojanfoe The web service just needs strings that have Somekey value and not SomeKey value1, value2, etc. - I am constructing an NSDictionary that has other key/value pairs that are needed for the final web service call. Which is just a GET request with AFNetworking and gets an XML feed back.

Comment: @dreamlax I am expecting to get one NSDictionary that has the same key multiple times, with different values each time. Just setting it the normal way, obviously overrides the last key. Maybe I could build a second array and use that inside an NSDictionary?

Comment: how do you expect to set mutiple different objects for one particular key in an `NSDictionary` without using further `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` objects as values? do you understand the concept of the `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @Tander what I'm saying is, what value is going to be returned when you use `objectForKey:@"SomeKey"` on this dictionary? How will the dictionary know what `"SomeKey"` you are referring to, the first, second or third?

Comment: @dreamlax I will never be asking for NSDictionary for the values again, once I have set them. I'm setting them, making the rest of the NSDictionary - send to web service and parse the response using model objects and XML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paramsArray = @[@{@"SomeKey": @"value1"},
                         @{@"SomeKey": @"value2"},
                         @{@"SomeKey": @"value3"},
                         @{@"OtherKey": @"value4"}];

    [paramsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *paramDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        [paramDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key,NSString *value, BOOL *stop){
            //apply the key and value on the HTTP request
        }];
    }];
```

The framework you are using accepts the NSDictionary format. You need to edit the framework to suit your needs.

**Edit**

You need to edit the AFNetworking code where it applies the parameters. Your initWithURL method takes urlParameters as NSDictionary. But according to my answer you need to pass NSArray with collection of NSDIctionary elements.

What needs to be done inorder to get this work is, in AFNetworking code the urlParameters has to be checked and handled. if urlParameters is NSDictionary then let the code behave as it is. If its NSArray then you need to do the "Applying HTTP parameters" yourself.

Comment: This is very close to what I need actually. However, I am not creating the array statically. its created using a different web service. Is there a way to do this with a mutable array?

Comment: @Tander you can use NSMutableArray for paramsArray and add dictionary objects into it using addObject method.

Comment: It seems I may have to get the Java debs to look at their web service. If put this into an NSDictionary inside an array it fails. I think the web service expects key/vale .. key/vale and not key1/value then inside key1 key/valye key/value if that makes sense?

Comment: You can fix it from your end. Not to bother Java devs to change webservice. How do you make the POST request? Which framework do you use. Or are you just using  NSURL connection. Please paste some code how you are making web request.

Comment: That would be pretty dam sweet if I can fix it my end. I'll update my question with the basic layout of the web service request

Comment: I have updated my question. Does this make it a little clearer? I can add more code if its needed.

Comment: updated the answer please check and modify your AFNEtworking code.

Comment: Appreciate your help with this. However, the problem is I cannot make the request by it self. It has to have other parameters, that every request needs. So, things like authId, search parameters for the type of search. This last web service call is to filter a previous search using the same values. So, modifying it would mean making a request that would only have half the parameters needed. I like your idea though Im going to expire it some more.. maybe there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it in such a way that the NSDictionary is inside the array?

For example:

```
[
{SomeKey:value1},
{SomeKey:value2},
{SomeKey:value3}
]
```

Comment: The final call to the web service needs to be an NSDictionary. Maybe with your approach I could do that and add the resulting array to another nsdictionary ?